# Getting "Missing :action key on routes definition" when I try and create a route with a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app with Rails 5.  I would like to create a route to search through names in my model taht would look like

```
/people/search/search_str
```

So I created the below route in my config/routes.rb file

```
  resources :people do
    collection do
      get 'image/:id', :to => "people#image", :as => 'image'
      get 'ranks', :to => "people#ranks", :as => 'ranks'
      get 'search/:search(.:format)', to: :search
    end
  end
```

but this results in the below error

```
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:329:in `check_part': Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:318:in `check_controller_and_action'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:252:in `normalize_options!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `initialize'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:69:in `new'
```

What's the right way to construct my route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
get 'search/:search(.:format)', to: 'people#search'
```